# React get inputs value without binding to a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a Database table containing every needed info while uploading a file, so the inputs have to change every time according to the file type chosen so I cannot bind them to a state or use Ref.

Is there any way to get every input's value?

EDIT:

small code example

```
const [inputs, loading] = useFetch(url);

return (
<>
   {inputs.map((input) =>
      <Fragment key={input.key}>
         <div className="row">
           <label>{input.label}</label>
           <input type="text" placeholder={input.label} maxLength={input.maxLength} required={input.required} />
         </div>
      </Fragment>
    )}
<>
);
```

Comment: It's not clear why you can't make use of state for this.  Please provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate specifically what problem you are observing in that example.

Comment: I cannot use the state as the inputs are loaded from a db table, so they can be just username and email or username, city, email, postal code. I cannot know which inputs are gonna be rendered. Im gonna TRY to leave a minimal code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're fetching data from a server in no way means that you *can't use state*.  Fetching data from a server and putting it in state is a very common use case.

Take a look at the Managed State example for [`useFetch`](https://use-http.com/).  Use that to load your data:

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([]);
const { get, post, response, loading, error } = useFetch(baseUrl);

useEffect(() => {
  loadInitialInputs();
}, []);

const loadInitialInputs = async () => {
  const initialInputs = await get(relativeUrl);
  if (response.ok) {
    setTodos(initialInputs);
  }
};
```

(Note how `url` has been split into `baseUrl` and `relativeUrl`.)

Now your `inputs` is *in state*.  And you can update that state with `setInputs`.  For example:

```
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder={input.label}
  maxLength={input.maxLength}
  required={input.required}
  value={input.value}
  onChange={e => handleChange(e, input.key)}
/>
```

(If `input.value` is initially `undefined` then this could produce warnings about changing from an uncontrolled component to a controlled component.  You can modify `loadInitialInputs` to add that property, for example: `setTodos(initialInputs.map(i => ({...i, value: ''})));`)

And your `handleChange` function might look like this:

```
const handleChange = (e, key) => {
  const existingInput = inputs.find(i => i.key === key);
  if (existingInput) {
    const updatedInput = { ...existingInput, value: e.target.value };
    setInputs([...inputs.map(i => {
      if (i.key === key) {
        return updatedInput;
      } else {
        return i;
      }
    })]);
  }
};
```

There are various other ways to structure it, but the overall idea is that updating the "input" simply involves finding the target object in the array (based on the `key` value) and updating state to a new array with an updated version of that object.

---

Overall the point here is that you *can* use state with data fetched from the server.  All you have to do is... put that data in state.

---

Aside... If your `useFetch` is not the one I found via Google, that's okay.  The same *concept* still applies, however you are fetching data from the server.  Just put that data in state and then you can use state.

Comment: I had this same exact idea, to load every input inside of an objects array and then just access those values. I was only missing the setInputs logic that you provided, too hard for me :). Thanks.